# Why does adding laser-controles in Aframe not work, when also using the Aframe-Vimeo-Component?

Tags: aframe, vimeo, vimeo-api

When in VR Mode in the VR headset (oculus quest), the laser controls do not work when using the vimeo component.
Does anyone know why this is? or have a workaround ?

Working code example below without vimeo, lasers work fine:

```
<a-scene >
    <a-videosphere ></a-videosphere>
  <a-box color="tomato" depth="2" height="4" width="0.5" position="0 2.4 -8"></a-box>
  <a-entity  laser-controls="hand: left"  raycaster="objects: .collidable" line="color: #26608c"></a-entity>
  <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: .collidable" line="color: #26608c"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

NOT working code example, laser controls are gone :

```
<a-scene >
    <a-videosphere vimeo="id: XXXXXXXXXX; autoplay: true;" ></a-videosphere>
  <a-box color="tomato" depth="2" height="4" width="0.5" position="0 2.4 -8"></a-box>
  <a-entity  laser-controls="hand: left"  raycaster="objects: .collidable" line="color: #26608c"></a-entity>
  <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: .collidable" line="color: #26608c"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

here's the glitch project:

https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me

https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me/working

https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me/notworking

Thanks a lot

Comment: Without code that people can run and debug it’ll be hard to help. I recommend using glitch https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: here's the glitch project:

https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me
https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me/working
https://stormy-melodious-feta.glitch.me/notworking

Thanks a lot